# inflexion points of a composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

Let's consider a smooth positive bounded and non-increasing function $h$ over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ (for example some kind of decreasing sigmoid).

A) Is it true that if $h$ has only one inflexion point, then so does $h\circ h$?
Any proof or counter-example would be much welcome.

B) If $h = f \circ g$ where $f,g$ are positive sigmoid-like (smooth and bounded) functions on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ with a single inflexion point and $f$ non-decreasing and $g$ non-increasing, then can $h$ or $h\circ h$ have more than one inflexion point?

Comment: I think what you want is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: which leads to a complication but since you specified "smooth" you can operate by factoring the zero's out locally and examining the requirements at just the zero's with the quotient as factors.  I find it hard to believe this question was asked 26 days ago.  If this hint is insufficient  I will work out the solution; I guess 50 points might be worth the complications :)

Comment: @rrogers Thanks for the link! If I understand well, Faà di Bruno's formula results from applying the chain rule multiple times, right? That's what I did for the specific case I mentioned and I could actually compute the second derivative. But what if you don't have an expression for f and g? Also I am not sure what you mean by "facturing the zero's out locally" in this context.

Comment: If you don't have an expression then you have to resolve the issue symbolically as a set of conditions.  I'll write up my thoughts.

Comment: I think A is false.(Hence B is false, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $g(x)=-\frac{7 x^3}{2}+\frac{21 x^2}{2}-\frac{85 x}{8}+\frac{33}{8}$, and set
$f(x)=\begin{cases}g^{-1}(x)&\text{if $0\le x\le 4$}\\ h(x)&\text{if $x>4$}\end{cases}$

We choose $h$ without inflexion points, positive and decreasing, such that $f$ is smooth. 
This is possible, since $g^{-1}(4)\approx  0.0119041928166$ and $(g^{-1})'(4)\approx -0.0963716$. Moreover $g^{-1}$ is decreasing and has only one inflexion point, namely $x=1/2$, $g^{-1}(x)=1$, hence $f$ satisfies the required properties.

But $f\circ f$ has three inflexion points, at $x_1=0.501059728212457, f(f(x_1))=0.5030949274084365$,

$x_2=0.7056987251370224$, $f(f(x_2))=0.6911169347561876$ and

$x_3=0.9990219172667842$, $f(f(x_3))=0.9971533801370549$.

This can be seen, considering that $f([0,4])=[0.0119,1.5]$ and $f(f([0,4]))\sim[0.35943651640802904,1.4956349330112384]$, and so $(f\circ f)(x)$ is given by $(g^{-1}\circ g^{-1})(x)$ for $x$ in that interval.

Now $g\circ g$ is strictly increasing in the interval $[0.35943651640802904,1.4956349330112384]$ and has three inflexion points, hence each of the inflexion points yields an inflexion point of $f\circ f$.

Note that all numerical values are approximate.

Comment: Nice example for part A), thanks! I wonder if it's possible to use this strategy for part B)?

Comment: In B you want $f\ne g$? Else B implies A.

Comment: Yes, in B $f$ in increasing wheres $g$ is decreasing.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you told us how you came up with those coefficients in $g$.

Comment: Then you have a typo in B, both are said to be non-decreasing.

Comment: I searched for $g$ cubic with $g(1)=1/2$, $g(1/2)=1$, $g'(1)=-1/8$ and $g''(1)=0$. This yields a decreasing cubic with an inflection point at $(1,1/2)$, and the image from the inflection point is "far away" from that point, so I expected two inflection points, one near the original inflection point ($x=1$) and one near the pre-image of the inflection point ($x=1/2$). Actually I was lucky and got three inflection points.

Comment: The same strategy should work for part B.

Comment: The general idea is that if you compose an affine linear function $f$ with a function $g$ with an inflexion point (in any order), then you obtain an inflexion point, and if the function $f$ is only approximately affin linear, you obtain an inflection point nearby.