# sigmoid $\circ$ sigmoid = sigmoid?

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples, function-and-relation-composition

The question is whether the concatenation of two *sigmoid function* must again be a sigmoid function.

> **Definition**. A bounded and two-times differentiable function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is called *sigmoid function* if $f'\not=0$ and there is *exactly one* $x\in\Bbb R$ with $f''(x)=0$.

Here is an example:

[image]

Given two sigmoid-functions $f$ and $g$, the function $h:=f\circ g$ is obviously bounded and two times differentiable. Also $h'\not=0$ is not hard to see. I even know that there is an inflection point (i.e. a value $x$ with $h''(x)=0$). But I failed to show that there is only one!

I admit that my initial motivation for this question comes from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411963/415941) post. I thought this would be one way to attack it in an elegant way. Still hard, though. Also no idea if there might be counterexamples.

Comment: I don't think so, because the range of the inner function may be much smaller than $\mathbb{R}$ so that the "sigmoid character" of the outer function can be significantly hindered.

Comment: @Ian I thought this will only make the range of the concatenation-sigmoid smaller. Would be still a sigmoid. I believe this mostly because I found no counterexample.

Comment: It seems that the saturation phenomenon will be much heavier in the composition.

Comment: This is a strange definition of "sigmoid function". What if $f''>0$ everywhere except at the one point where it is $0,$ so that the function is everywhere concave or everywhere convex, thus with no inflection point? By your proposed definition, that is still a sigmoid function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think then the function would not be bounded anymore.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752789/inflexion-points-of-a-composition-of-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $g(x)=10\tanh(x/10)+\tanh(10x)$ and $f(x)=g(x-5)$.

$g(x)$:

[image]

$g'(x):$

[image]

$g''(x):$

[image]

$f(g(x)):$

[image]

Note that despite how the graphs look, all derivatives are obviously bounded.

Comment: This has derivative zero in places...

Comment: I believe that when you try to smooth $g$ you will create several inflection points because the resulting function will switch multiple times between convex and concave.

Comment: @M.Winter: I'm afraid your belief is incorrect, see my edit.

Comment: @Rahul I see. This loosk very good. Thank you!